# Fragment is not getting popped using navigation graph

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-navigation-graph

I am building an app where first time it opens fragment1 to get user details and once user forwards to next fragment2, I am saving the details and setting a boolean variable `isUserRegistered` to true in `SharedPreferences` so that when the user opens the app next time, he/she will be directly taken to the fragment2. I am using using navigation graph to handle these things.

Following is the code:

```kotlin
//declared at the top in onCreateView() of fragment
val prefs = appContext!!.getSharedPreferences("expense_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Once user clicks Continue button, following actions are defined (only showing the relevant code)

```kotlin
val editor = prefs.edit()
editor.putBoolean("isUserRegistered", true)
editor.apply()
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_getStartedFragment_to_homeFragment)
```

and in order to redirect user when he/she visits app the next time, I have written following code:

```kotlin
//in the same onCreateView() of fragment1
val isUserRegistered = prefs.getBoolean("isUserRegistered", false)
if (isUserRegistered)
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_getStartedFragment_to_homeFragment)
```

and following is my navigation file in which I have also added `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` in both of the navigations.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/getStartedFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/getStartedFragment"
        android:name="net.softglobe.expensemanager.GetStartedFragment"
        android:label="fragment_get_started"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_get_started" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_getStartedFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="net.softglobe.expensemanager.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_getStartedFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/getStartedFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Still, when user navigates from fragment1 to fragment2, the previous fragment is not getting popped out. And when user presses back button from fragment2, the compiler is coming again on fragment1 and because of that navigation code piece (shown above) it is navigating user to fragment2, as `isUserRegistered` is true. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) article

> To pop destinations when navigating from one destination to another, add an app:popUpTo attribute to the associated  element. app:popUpTo tells the Navigation library to pop some destinations off of the back stack as part of the call to navigate(). The attribute value is the ID of the most recent destination that should remain on the stack.
>
> You can also include app:popUpToInclusive="true" to indicate that the
> destination specified in app:popUpTo should also be removed from the
> back stack.

You're not providing the needed fragment to where you should have been popped, something like `app:popUpTo="@id/getStartedFragment"`

Comment: I have already written `app:destination="@id/getStartedFragment"` to do that work. Also, tried changing with `app:popUpTo="@id/getStartedFragment"`, but not a luck.

Comment: @AshishJoshi, let me confirm.
You tried

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/getStartedFragment"
        android:name="net.softglobe.expensemanager.GetStartedFragment"
        android:label="fragment_get_started"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_get_started" >

  <action
            android:id="@+id/action_getStartedFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/getStartedFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried putting that in another fragment. It is working as I want now. Thank you so much for help.